# Is it possible to know if a star is on ? (JQuery Raty Plugin)

Tags: jquery, rating, raty

First of all, excuse-me if I do some english mistakes, I am french. I am using the raty jquery plugin in order to put something in my favorites, I have got 1 star which can be clicked to set something in my favorites. As I said in the title, I need to know if that star is on or not.

I already tried to use the score value but it returns the score of the star under the mouse (always 1) and not the actual selected score (undefined or 1 in my case).

Here is my code:

```
$('.fav-star').raty({
    mouseover: function(score,evt) {
        if(1){ //is raty on ?
            $(this).raty('set', { hints: ['Retire from favorites']});
        }
        else {
            $(this).raty('set', { hints: ['Add to favorites']});
        }
    }
}
```

I just need to know what is the right condition to put in the if(). Thanks for your help !

Comment: what'll happen if you use `if( score==1)`, in this case you're using `if(1)` which will be always true

Comment: try `if( score )` instead  of `if(1)`

Comment: I don't know how to check if the star is on, that's why I put 1, it's temporary. I tried with if(score==1) but it's always true as my star score is 1 and the score check is after the click event.

Comment: @AlivetoDie if(score) is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.
I am working with laravel so I just put an id to each star with $loop->iteration and then accessed to the score with $('#fav-star{{$loop->iteration}} > input').val().
It looks like this now.

```
$('#fav-star{{$loop->iteration}}').raty({
   //some code
   mouseover: function(score,evt) {
        if($('#fav-star{{$loop->iteration}} > input').val() == 1){
            $('#fav-star{{$loop->iteration}}').raty('set', { hints: ['Retire from favorites']});
        }
        else {
            $('#fav-star{{$loop->iteration}}').raty('set', { hints: ['Add to favorites']});
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.